# Should electric dryer work on NEMA 10-30 receptacle with 163 V to ground in commercial building with 3 phase service? USA

Tags: three-phase

An animal shelter (in USA) where I volunteer has a new 240V Maytag electric dryer that will not operate (when "on" is pressed, the electronic panel gives a single brief flash of all LED's, that's all).  The Maytag service tech says the power is defective because he measures 163V from hot leg to ground; he expects 120V (as one finds in residential split-phase 240V) and says the problem is in the power wiring, not the machine.  We have no other power source to try.

The dryer has a three terminal panel with two hots and a ground (no independent neutral), to which a NEMA 10-30 cord/plug is attached and correctly wired.  It is plugged into a NEMA 10-30 receptacle (which is incorrectly wired in that the neutral pin is connected to ground).  The voltages at the receptacle and inside the dryer are 240 hot to hot, and 165 from one hot to ground and 169 on second hot to ground.  The building is commercial and has three-phase service.

I think all this is as it should be, given that the building has 3-phase service and no neutral is employed, and the problem is in the dryer.  Am I correct, or have I missed something?  (I'm not looking for an explanation of three-phase delta/Y or center-tapped transformers, just whether the power wiring to the receptacle is correct and the voltages normal, and the problem is in the dryer.)

Comment: 163 V phase to ground is unusually high, but phase to ground voltage shouldn't ever matter. If it does, someone at Maytag has designed the dryer worryingly wrongly.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad neutral somewhere. Have it inspected.

Comment: @Jeroen3 No, sounds like "High Leg Delta" type of system.

Comment: For three-phase power, I would expect 208 V between phases.  This question may be better in the DIY/Home improvment stack - there are several regular posters there who are familiar with AC pwoer wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the site has 3-phase service with the "High Leg Delta" type.

It should have 240VAC between two phases and all three phases, and both phases should have 120VAC to the third pole, neutral, and to ground.

So, the voltages in the receptacle are not OK.

The third phase is the "high leg" and should have 173V to neutral.

Better call an electrician, the voltages are not what they should be.

Also if the machine uses two phases and the third wire as neutral for something based on one of the live connections, it has seen overvoltage and may be damaged.

Answer (score 0):

The dryer is wired/designed for 240v single phase.  Any 2 hot legs of a 3 phase circuit are 120 degrees out of each other.  This might not matter for a SMPS or even if it was wired for the 120/240v split phase(i.e. with a neutral), but will not work for a 240v AC motor.

You might be able to source a transformer that you could feed with 1 leg of that 3 phase and step up to 240v, but it would be better to return this and buy a proper device for your power.  Alternatively, a VFD type device might also work.

Comment: Please clarify: what is SMPS?  How can 2 legs be 120 deg out of phase with each other?  They may be 120 d out with respect to a third point (as 3 phase power does), but the two poles of any AC signal would be out by 180 d, I would think.

Comment: @MadMonty I think _SMPS_ means [Switched-mode power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply)